# Deleting Used Blob in AppEngine DevServer

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am using GAE BlobStore to store avatars for user profiles. Users have the option to upload avatars, and if they are uploading an avatar while they already have one, the old avatar blob is deleted and replaced with the new blob. This works as expected on GAE in production.

In GAE local testing on the DevServer (on Windows 7), the old blob is not deleted and a security exception is thrown. This seems to be because the old blob is currently being used by the DevServer since it is being served as an avatar for the current user profile. When I try to manually delete the blob from the appengine-generated files in Windows File Explorer, I get the message that I can't do so because the file is currently in use. If I try to delete a blob that is not currently being served as an avatar that works fine.

Is there a way to get the DevServer to give up its hold on the blob so that it can be deleted? It works fine in production, so this is not a huge deal but it would make testing a bit easier.

Comment: Is this the same issue: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4744 . Perhaps SDK version 1.7.2 that was suggested might help?

Comment: Yup, looks like that's it, thanks. I'm on 1.7.5 and still have the issue, I guess they don't plan on fixing it ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pending issue about this problem on the App Engine [bugtracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4744).

Progress on the fix seems to be *slow*..